# How do you update Xcode command line tool on OSX to the latest version?

Tags: xcode

How do you update Xcode command line tool on OSX to the latest version?

"As of Mavericks you can choose to install only the Xcode command line tools instead of the whole Xcode package." How do you update Xcode command line tool? It's not on the list of app store update, and seems not updated when I update Xcode..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Note: In OS X 10.9, Software update notifies you when new versions of the command-line tools are available for update."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html

I found this note, so it seems not updated or installed from command line, separately from xcode itself, even though it WAS on the list of app store update.